# Pass class property name to subroutine

Tags: vb.net

I have a class called "person", with properties. A few examples of the property names would be...

```
person.name
person.surname
person.firstname
```

I'm trying to pass this property NAME to a subroutine... not sure if I can even do this. I want to do this because I will have 100's of properties, and I don't want 100's of IF then statements.

This is what I'm currently doing, and I would like to clean it up with a method. Picture 100 if then statements like this, checking for a different property name.

```
If propname= "FirstName" Then
       If GetSet.caseexact = True Then
              If GetSet.casesensativity = True Then
                   View.Filter = Function(m) DirectCast(m, person).FirstName = s
              Else
                   View.Filter = Function(m) DirectCast(m, person).FirstName.ToLower = s.ToLower
              End If
       Else
              If GetSet.casesensativity = True Then
                   View.Filter = Function(m) DirectCast(m, person).FirstName.Contains(s)
              Else
                   View.Filter = Function(m) DirectCast(m, person).FirstName.ToLower.Contains(s.ToLower)
              End If
       End If
End If
```

I'm trying to clean this up with a method, so I can just pass the property name to a method... if this is even possible.

```
Public Sub properties(filterstring As String, getProp as person)
    View.Filter = Function(m) DirectCast(m, person).getProp = filterstring 
End Sub
```

Any guidance on how to get this to work, or best approach?

Comment: You should describe *what* you are trying to do - *how* isnt possible that way because `getProp` cant be a variable parameter and a property of something else. You could use Reflection, but I suspect there is an easier way.  What the heck is `GetSet`?

Answer (score 1):

Reflection would work.  If the properties are **Public**, though, then you can simply the code using `CallByName()`:

```
    Dim p As New Person
    p.FirstName = "Mike"

    Dim s As String = "Bob"
    Dim propname As String = "FirstName"
    View.Filter = (CallByName(p, propname, CallType.Get) = s)
    ' < or >
    View.Filter = (CallByName(p, propname, CallType.Get).ToString.ToLower = s)
```